# Does Saki have Extract Brewing?

Tags: extract-brewing

I haven't even done my first batch of full grain brewing for beer. I certainly don't want to learn Saki (at the moment), but I would enjoy brewing some extract version of it (for now).

Are there any suppliers whom sell an extract version of Saki, or is this not possible for whatever reason?

Comment: There is Dry Rice Extract (used in standard brewing to lighten the body), you could investigate using that plus koji to ferment it maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen nor heard of an extract for sake.

Answer (score 1):

Sake both ferments and converts rice starches to sugars at the same time (think fermenting in the mash) so an extract version of sake isn't really going to turn out tasting like sake.

I made Sake long before I switched to all grain brewing you don't need a mash tun since you're basically mashing in your fermentor, so don't let your lack of being an all grain brewer stop you. However making sake is a lot of work, you have to steam (or boil) all of the rice (10+ pounds depending on how much you're trying to make) and add it in intervals every 18 hours (if you're being traditional).

Here are the instructions I followed if you want to give it a try: http://www.taylor-madeak.org/index.php/2008/02/29/how-to-make-sake-at-home-a-taylor-made-g